# Permission issue with charon-cmd on ubuntu

Tags: ipsec, ubuntu-16.04, strongswan, vpn-client

I am using charon-cmd to connect to strongswan vpn on a ubuntu host.  When I use the command, it gives me some kind of permission error.

```
root@8add2362b05f:~# sudo charon-cmd --host example.com --p12 ipsec_vpn_vert/client.cert.p12  --identity client@example.com 
00[KNL] kernel-libipsec plugin requires CAP_NET_ADMIN capability
00[LIB] plugin 'kernel-libipsec': failed to load - kernel_libipsec_plugin_create returned NULL
00[KNL] kernel-netlink plugin might require CAP_NET_ADMIN capability
00[KNL] unable to bind XFRM event socket
00[NET] installing IKE bypass policy failed
00[NET] installing IKE bypass policy failed
00[NET] enabling UDP decapsulation for IPv6 on port 50817 failed
00[NET] installing IKE bypass policy failed
00[NET] installing IKE bypass policy failed
00[NET] enabling UDP decapsulation for IPv4 on port 50817 failed
00[LIB] feature CUSTOM:libcharon in critical plugin 'charon-cmd' has unmet dependency: CUSTOM:kernel-ipsec
00[KNL] received netlink error: Operation not permitted (1)
00[KNL] unable to create IPv4 routing table rule
00[KNL] received netlink error: Operation not permitted (1)
00[KNL] unable to create IPv6 routing table rule
00[LIB] failed to load 1 critical plugin feature
00[KNL] received netlink error: Operation not permitted (1)
00[KNL] received netlink error: Operation not permitted (1)
root@8add2362b05f:~#
```

I am doing this on a docker container.

I tried setcap but that made the situation even worse.

```
root@8add2362b05f:~# setcap cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=eip /usr/sbin/charon-cmd 
root@8add2362b05f:~# getcap /usr/sbin/charon-cmd /usr/sbin/charon-cmd = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip
root@8add2362b05f:~# 
root@8add2362b05f:~# 
root@8add2362b05f:~# sudo charon-cmd --host example.com --p12 ipsec_vpn_vert/client.cert.p12  --identity client@example.com 
sudo: unable to execute /usr/sbin/charon-cmd: Operation not permitted
root@8add2362b05f:~#
```

Any clues on how to solve this?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` here? It appears unnecessary.

Comment: True.  Can be removed and was no change in the behavior.   Just thought if sudo will add any caps to the command before executing.

Comment: My guess is you need to give the Docker container the required capability  or run it as privileged container.

Comment: Isnt it trying to modify its own interfaces?  In that case why we need to run the container in privileged mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should run the Docker container with --privileged option.
Or you can use a VM instead of a Docker container.

Comment: That indeed solved the problem.

Comment: Running a container as `--privileged` should be avoided if possible, and in this case, it seems as if adding `--cap-add NET_ADMIN` would fix the basic issue